# I'd like to know which tense is appropriate

Tags: grammaticality, tense

I'm confused which tense I should choose in the following sentence. I got an announcement from my school that I would be in charge of an additional class from next month. In this case, what should I say?

> I was assigned to another class from next month.

> I'll be assigned to another class.

> I've been assigned to another class.

Could you tell me which sentence is appropriate in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would normally use the present perfect construction:

> *I've been assigned another class*.

If you want to pin down exactly *when* in the past you were assigned that class, however, you have to use the past form:

> *Yesterday I was assigned another class*.

If you have not yet been assigned that class but you know that that is going to happen you use the future construction:

> *Sometime next week I'll be assigned another class.*

A note about idiom, in addition to that which jwpat7 provided: *assigned to* is not incorrect, but at least in US English we usually use just *assigned* for an additional task or responsibility. *Assigned to* is more often used when you are moved from one single class or group or unit to a different one:

> It's official, I've been assigned to Underwriting.
>   I'm very disappointed; I've been assigned to Prof. Sartorius' class, and I really wanted to work with Prof. Underhill.
>   John's no longer in Operations; he's been assigned to Admin.

Comment: Then if I get transferred to another city like Tokyo next month, can I say, " I've been assigned to Tokyo. "?

Comment: I would also point out that "*I'll be assigned to **another** class next month*" could be interpreted as "*I'll no longer be assigned to me current class as of next month*"  If, in fact, you'll have both the current and the new class you might say, "*I've been assigned an **additional** class starting next month.*"

Comment: @tennisgirl Yes. If you were just "assigned" Tokyo, no "to", you would be in charge of Tokyo.

Comment: @Jim  Indeed. And I think probably a struggling adjunct prof who really wants that additional class would say "I'm getting" or "They're giving me".

Comment: I'm getting a little confused.  So when I got a notification to be tansferred to Tokyo for two years, for example, should I say " I've been assigned Tokyo," without putting " to" ?  Sorry for many questions.

Comment: @tennisgirl No, you should say "I've been assigned **to** Tokyo". *I've been assigned Tokyo* implies *Tokyo has been assigned to me*, that is *I am now in charge of the Tokyo office*.

Comment: Now it's clear when I should put "to" in the sentence. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

There are no real problems with any of the phrases  “I was assigned to another class”,   “I'll be assigned to another class”, and   “I've been assigned to another class”.  However, the phrase “from next month” is incorrect or at least not idiomatic in most strains of English.  Instead use  “beginning next month”,  “as of next month”,  “starting next month”, “that starts next month”, etc.

Comment: I think the "from next month" usage happens because that form exists in some foreign languages. I started writing "from next month" in English because Japanese persons would translate 来月から that way. 来月= next month; から= from (as a beginning time marker).

Comment: When I tanslate from Japanese into English, I would always say, " from tomorrow, next month, or something". But I should try not to translate that way. I learned a very good point here.